# How to change a list of hashtags into strings separated by commas?

Tags: javascript, arrays, instagram

I have a list of instagram hashtags that go like this

#love #life #instagram #cool

but I want them to look like this

'love', 'life', 'instagram', 'cool'

is there any way to make that happen using javascript, or is there an existing program that does that? I want to have a small code that takes those hashtags as input, and outputs in the format that I want. I only know JavaScript so I doubt any other programming language advice will be useful, unless there's a program that does that already.

Comment: What do you have tried so far? Please post your [mcve]

Comment: Is your data currently in the form of  `var list = ['#love','#life','#instagram','#cool'];` or is it more like `var list = '#love #life #instagram #cool';` ?

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```js
let input = $('#my_input').text().split('#');
let output = '';
$.each( input, function( key, value ) {
 if(value != ''){
  if(input.length-1 != key){
     output += "'" + value + "', "
  }else{
   output += "'" + value + "'"
  }
 }
});

$('#my_input').text(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 'love', 'life', 'instagram', 'cool' -->
<div id='my_input'>#love #life #instagram #cool</div>
```

or something like this (from nullqube but added some changes):

```js
let strData = $('#my_input').text();

let list = strData.split("#");
//remove first item
list.shift();
let res = list.map(function(item){
 if(item != ''){
     return "'" + item + "'";
  }
}).join(", ");

$('#my_input').text(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 'love', 'life', 'instagram', 'cool' -->
<div id='my_input'>#love #life #instagram #cool</div>
```